# How do I fix a Capacitor Community Admob banner not pushing footer content?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using the Capacitor Admob Comunity plugin to put a banner on my app.

It runs smoothly, but the banner doesn't work like I thought it would.
It should push the webview up. And it is currently overlaying the content in the footer.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

This is my bannerOptions

```
private _bannerOptions: BannerAdOptions = {
    adId: BANNER_ADID,
    adSize: BannerAdSize.BANNER,
    position: BannerAdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    margin: 0,
    isTesting: false
}
```

[image]